# How to save a tree view model and reload it

Tags: qt, qt5

This is the header file for my treeItem.

```
class TreeItem
{
public:
    explicit TreeItem( Container *data , TreeItem *parent = 0 );
    ~TreeItem();
    TreeItem *parent();
    void appendChild(TreeItem *child);
    TreeItem& operator = (const TreeItem &item);
    TreeItem *child(int iNumber);
    int childCount() const;
    int childNumber() const;
    Container data() const ;
    Container* GetContainer();
    bool setData(Container* data , QVariant value);
    void setContainer( Container* data);
    bool insertChildren(int position, int count );
    bool removeChildren( int position  , int count );
    void removeChild(int row);
    void removeChild(TreeItem* itm);
    QList<TreeItem*> children();
    std::string getChildName(int row);
    std::string getName();
    int row() const;
    void insertChild(int pos, TreeItem *child);

private:
    QList<TreeItem*> childItems;
    Container* itemData;
    TreeItem* parentItem;
};
```

[image]

Container class data .

```
class Container : public QObject
{ 
    private:
    std::string stdstrContainerName;
    std::string stdstrPluginType;
    Geometry* Geom;
    Sum_Material Material;
    Transformation transformation;
    Transformation transformationPrev;
    Sum_Texture_2D texture;
    Sum_Texture_2D texture2;
    Sum_Texture_CubeMap cubeMapTexture;
    float OpacityPercent;
    SumTransformationDecl::TransformationMode mode;
    WavefrontRenderer* wavefrontrenderer;
    bool bDrawBoundingBox;
    float boundingBoxOffset;
    std::vector< SumChannel* > Channels;
    std::vector< std::shared_ptr<Sum_Function> > Functions;
    BlendMode containerBlend;
```

I want to save all the items in the model to a file and should be able to reload the tree model from the file.

I don't have any clue how to do this.

1) what should be the  file format , can i create my own format for this ?

2) TreeItem contains a Container object as data item but currently i want to just save the tree structure and load it as step 1.

Comment: You don't need to save a tree model. You should rather save the data your model uses. I guess it's `Container`.

Comment: @vahancho my tree structure has a hierarchy than how do i put it back in the same hierarchy.

Comment: Usually, for hierarchical data people use either XML or JSON formats to serialize it. How your data looks like, by the way?

Comment: @vahancho i have loaded the image for the tree structure.

Comment: When I saw a title and tags I've expected inheritance from [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) or its descendants.